# Cannot find interface declaration error Xcode 10.2 after Carthage update

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

I have updated the carthage after updated myxcode to 10.2 , And the Carthage framework class is not found alert I am getting .

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'ChartMarkerImage', superclass
>   of 'BalloonMarker' ?

My project swift version was 4.0 still.

[image]

But the file is available in Carthage framework .
[image]

What was went wrong here ?

What i tried is

```
Set toolchain to SWIFT_4_2 but no luck.
Added #import <chart/chart.h> in pch file still getting error.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's Carthage [issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/pull/2748). The fixed release will soon available

**UPD:** Version 0.33.0 https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases/tag/0.33.0

Answer (score 2):

Update your carthage version to 0.33.0 from either of the below option

1. download pkg file from [link](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases)
2. update carthage by homebrew

after updating use "carthage update --platform ios" command